# The output is not expected as I am

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uibutton, output

The problem I have is that the console output is not matched to the simulator display.

I want the 'numberOfCardUpward' to match what the simulator does, but that doesn't happen.

My code looks like this:
[image]

So what's wrong with my code and how should I correct it?

PS: '1 2 3 1' is exactly the number of numberOfCardUpward

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not as an image

Comment: Kindly don't post code as a screenshot, rather paste the code snippet here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping all your cards, but only from 0 to the tag that was last tapped. Line 57 of your code.